# output whole list in C#

Tags: python, c#, linq, list-comprehension

in python language i can easily do this and output is whole list:

```
import random
list = [random.randrange(150) for i in range(10)]
print(list)
```

Can i do this thing in C# language without for cycle like this? Because output seperates my list's elements.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> ();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
list.Add(rnd.Next (150));
}
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++){
Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Move the console.writeline into the loop above. I have no clue why you have them in separate loops. Also, don’t tag this as visual studio code or visual studio unless it is related to one of those, and never tag it as both as they are two completely different IDEs.

Comment: What you mean about moving the console.writeline into the loop above?

Comment: _Console.WriteLine_ writes a ... line. Meaning the content and a newline character. What do you mean with _output seperates my list's elements_? If you want everything on a single line then use _Console.Write_

Comment: No, C# does not know how to print a list (or other object) as a single unit.  It's entirely up to you to print it the way you like.

Comment: in C# `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));` I think would be the "normal" approach. Another option would be to create your own extension method or even overriding a ToString() method ... I suppose you have options here if you want to explore different approaches, but as noted, C# is not python so not directly the same.

Comment: Then look at what you can do using _string.Join_ to simulate the phyton output

Comment: Side note, for creating the list, you can also do `Random rdn = new();` `var list = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x => rdn.Next(150)).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can do it in one line if you want as well. This code is also thread-safe but requires .NET 6.0 or higher due to the use of `Random.Shared`.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => Random.Shared.Next(150))));
```

This generates an `IEnumerable<int>` with random integers from 0 to 149 and then writes them to the `Console` separated by commas.

Comment: +1 for `Random.Shared`; side remark: `Select(_ => ...` (note `_` instead of `x`) for more readability - you ignore the argument

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, just curious... would `_` instead of `x` affect performance as well or is it there only for readability?

Comment: optimizer is smart enough to see that the argument is not used, so the code will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not a method generating a list of random integers in .NET, but why won't you write your own? For example:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> RandomEnumerable(int maxValue, int count, Random random = default)
    {
        if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
        }

        if (maxValue < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxValue));
        }

        random ??= Random.Shared;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return random.Next(maxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do your task in two lines like in phyton:

```
var randomList = MyEnumerable.RandomEnumerable(150, 10).ToList();
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", randomList)}]");
```

Comment: Side note: `var random = new Random();` is not a good practice; either pass `Random` to the method or use `Random.Shared` (or combine it; if passed `Random == default` use `Random,Shared`)

Comment: Good point, I'll improve this method.

Comment: Side note: `Random random = default` for readbility and `random ??= Random.Shared;` for readbility / compactness

Comment: Thank you for your notice again

Comment: You have covered *important practicle case* when we used `Random` with *seed* (reproducible random numbers): `var list = MyEnumerable.RandomEnumerable(150, 10, new Random(123)).ToList();`; my +1 for this.